# Error: control may reach end of non-void function in C

Tags: c, controls

I cannot figure out why this error is happening: `error: control may reach end of non-void function`

Here is the code:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {

    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (values[i] == value) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

I understand that the error means that the function may reach the end without returning anything, but I cannot figure out how that might happen.

Comment: The complier does not analyze that "deeply" the "sense" of the code in a function. Just add `return false;` at the end of the function. This will even make the first `if` unnecessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "control reaches end of non-void function" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean)

Comment: BTW, it looks like your loop only checks `values[0]`.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here and your homework's already done or you've given up on it years ago, but for completeness' sake I'd like to point out:

1) There's absolutely no need to break after return true; return exits the function so breaking out of the loop is redundant.

2) if (condition) return true; else return false; means you'll only test the condition one time. Simply put, i will never reach a value higher than 0.

Answer (score 14):

You are getting this error because if your `for` loop breaks due to breaking condition `i < n;` then it don't find any `return` statement after `for` loop (see the below, I mentioned in code as comment).

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (values[i] == value){
        return true;
        break;
    }
    else{ 
        return false;
    }
}
  // here you should add either return true or false     
}
```

If `for` loop break due to `i >= n` then control comes to the position where I commented and there is no `return` statement present. Hence you are getting an error "reach end of non-void function in C".

Additionally, remove `break` after `return` statement. if `return` executes then break never get chance to execute and break loop.

```
   return true;  -- it returns from here. 
    break;  -- " remove it it can't executes after return "
```

Check your compiler should give you a warning - 'unreachable code'.

Answer (score 6):

That compiler warning is not correct. Anyway, there is a bigger problem with your code:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {

    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (values[i] == value) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else {            // !
            return false; // ! <-- Here is the mistake.
        }                 // !
    }    
}
```

This code only checks `values[0] == value` and then always returns. It's happening because of that `else {return false;}`.

You should write it this way:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {

    if (n < 1) {
        return false;
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (values[i] == value) {
            return true;
            // break;  <- BTW, it's redundant.
        }
    }    
    return false;
}
```

Now, function checks entire `values` array and then returns `false` if there was no matches. But if it found a match, it will instantly return `true` witout checking other elements.

Also, compiler will not emit a warning for this code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is equivalent to

```
return (n > 0 && values [0] == value);
```

Either you are in the habit of writing very simple things in an excessively complicated way, or that code doesn't do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Some folks will probably hate this, but....

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {

   if (n < 1) {
      return false;
   }   

   bool ret = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      if (values[i] == value) {
         ret = true;
         break;
      }
   }    
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: Deals with issue mentioned by Joe Quinsey