# I have a function that has int a and int b all I have to do is find the max value

Tags: c, function, max

I keep getting the following error (warning: control may reach end of non void function [-Wreturn-type])

This is what I have right now.

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    if (b > a) {
        return a;
    }
    if (a > b) {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think will happen when `a == b` ? Incidentally, you return the **min** value not the **max** in the question title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: control may reach end of non-void function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410538/error-control-may-reach-end-of-non-void-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

If `b == a` then there is no explicit return value. Your compiler is warning you of that.

This is why you should *always* use a final `} else {` block.

Although adding

```
if (a == b){
    return a; // either would do
}
```

would be an immediate fix, such a change could cause you problems in the future, if you ever write a version of `min` that takes `double` types, and one of the inputs is `NaN`. No compiler I know of currently warns you of that.

Really though, you should ditch this function entirely and use the one from a respected library. For a whole host of technical reasons, the canonical way of writing `min` is to use

```
return (b < a) ? b : a;
```

Comment: *use the one from the C standard library.* I'm afraid there is no `min` function in the Standard C library.

Comment: @chqrlie Ha. That will teach me. I’ve edited. Could have sworn I had min, minf and so on at university. Posix perhaps?

Comment: I had the same feeling and it took me a while to check in the Standard... There is `int abs(int)` and floating point versions `double fmin(double x, double y);`, `float fminf(float x, float y);` and `long double fminl(long double x, long double y);`, but no integer `min` nor a generic version.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    if (b > a){
        return a;
    }
    if (a > b){
        return b;
    }
}
```

you missed the case where `a==b`

can be just

```
int min(int a, int b) {
  return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: ok changed for `<` rather than `<=` if you prefer, but that changes absolutely nothing on the result ^^

Comment: `return (b < a) ? b : a;` pretty please with sugar on top.

Comment: @Bathsheba that time I do not understand at all the interrest, please can you explain ?

Comment: bruno: ask that as a question, I'll be sure to upvote it.

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry but I prefer to follow the order of the parameters ;-)

Comment: Well that makes you a very naughty boy. Your way breaks the signed zero convention for 1's complement `int`.

Comment: I have already changed to please you, but I will not change for an upvote, I am not for sale ^^

Comment: But I'm not pleased since you break the convention!

Comment: @Bathsheba I am a rebel, and at my age I am afraid it is too late to change :-)

Comment: Respect.͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: (But note that the C tag is the final bastion for perfectionists - you might attract the odd downvote).

Comment: @Bathsheba did you noticed the more the initial problem is simple the more we discuss and have different points of view ? ^^

Comment: But my point of view is the correct one. Sorry but I can't resist that. My only problem is that I'm conceited. I'm too old to change that.

Comment: Different language I know but see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min

Comment: @Bathsheba: *ask that as a question, I'll be sure to upvote it*... be my guest :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552778/what-is-the-best-implementation-of-min