# What is the best implementation of min?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, min

Is there a difference between

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

and

```
int min(int a, int b) {
    return (b < a) ? b : a;
}
```

Is there any specific reason to prefer one over the other?

This question is specifically intended for both the C and the C++ languages. I understand these are different languages and a similar question was asked for C++ here: [Correct implementation of min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174447/correct-implementation-of-min) .

I am interested in reasons that may pertain to one language and not the other.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191408/discussion-on-question-by-chqrlie-what-is-the-best-implementation-of-min).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. The two implementations are equivalent under all defined circumstances. (An individual compiler might exhibit performance differences, but not functional differences.)

It would be different if the function weren't concerned solely with ints. Floating point numbers, as chux mentioned in a comment, can have both `a<b` and `b<a` false even when their bit patterns differ, as with negative/positive zero, or when at least one is a NaN. Technically this could also occur with an exotic (but standards-compliant) integer representation (through -0 or padding bits), but AFAIK no otherwise standards-compliant compiler does that.

Comment: Padding bits would not affect the values, so they would not affect evaluations of `a<b` or `b<a`. `-0` would not cause both `a<b` and `b<a` to be false; it should act like zero. If either `a` or `b` is a trap representation, then either `a<b` or `b<a` will trap, and the C standard does not provide any help for that.

Comment: Unisys still supports [a C compiler for its legacy OS-2200 mainframes](https://public.support.unisys.com/2200/docs/cp14.0/pdf/78310422-011.pdf) that uses one’s-complement signed integers and claims to be compliant with C89.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My thinking was that non-trapped padding bits could still be read through type punning, exposing the behavior difference if the values matched. But on reflection I don't think the standard guarantees that the same object representation would come out of the ternary as was present in the chosen operand.