# Error: control may reach end of non-void function c programming

Tags: c

```
void *returnMin(PQueue q){
  if (q.list == NULL){
    printf("List is empty.\n");
  } else if (q.list->head == NULL){
    printf("List is empty.\n");
  } else {
    return q.list->head;
  }
}
```

Currently working on Priority queues, everything seems to be working except when I try to return the min and max priorities, I get the error. We are using 3 structs, the 3rd one being a struct pointer.

Comment: Only one of those conditional code blocks returns a value for the function. The others do not, and there is no `return XXX;` at the end of the function.

Comment: you need to return something in all case, considering you visibly return a pointer you can return NULL in the two fist cases. WIthout a return the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: control may reach end of non-void function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410538/error-control-may-reach-end-of-non-void-function-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a pointer. Since the function returns something, and that something is likely being used somewhere else in your code, it *must* return a value in any possible case. Your function however does not do this, since only the last branch has a `return` statement. If you somehow enter `if (q.list == NULL)` you have no `return` statement to execute.

To fix this, return something meaningful (`NULL` is a good choice to indicate an error):

```
void *returnMin(PQueue q){
  if (q.list == NULL){
    printf("List is empty.\n");
    return NULL;
  } else if (q.list->head == NULL){
    printf("List is empty.\n");
    return NULL;
  } else {
    return q.list->head;
  }
}
```

Comment: The C standard does not require a non-void function to return a value. However, if the return value of the function is used, the standard does not define the behavior. If the calling function does not use the return value, the behavior is defined.

Comment: Wait really @EricPostpischil? That got me, I thought it did. Thanks. I suppose it makes sense to allow stuff like `exit()` being called in a function, or other functions like the libc wrapper for `execve`.