# Why do I get this error in this function?

Tags: function

```
int checkWinDiagonals(char board[N][M])
{

for(int i = 0; i < (N-3); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < (M-3); j++)
    {
 if(board[i][j] != ' ' && board[i][j] == board[i+1][j+1])
        {
if (board[i][j] == board[i+2][j+2] && board[i][j] == board[i+3][j+3])
    {
      return 1;
    }

        }
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < (N-3); i++)

{
 for(int j = 3; j < M; j++)
{
if(board[i][j] != ' ' && board[i][j] == board[i+1][j-1])
    {

if( board[i][j] == board[i+2][j-2] && board[i][j] == board[i+3][j-3])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
 }
}
```

I get this error "control reaches end of non-void function".Forget int main() because this is just a piece of the code in which it doesnt work.Do I have to put return (something); in some place?

Comment: Checkout the meaning of that error [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean)

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* format your code with consistent indentation to make errors like this a *lot* easier to spot.  But I suspect the problem is right here:

```
//...
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // right here
}
```

What happens at runtime if those loops have nothing over which to iterate and are skipped entirely?  Or various `if` blocks don't evaluate to true and are skipped?  The end of the function is reached and nothing is returned, but the function is declared to return an `int` so something *must* be returned.

You need to structure your code to always return a value in any logical case.  Which in this case may involve returning a default value at the end of none of the preceding logic returned anything.