# Control reaches end of non-void, despite having a return value

Tags: c

I received an error during compilation:

> src/smtp.c:208:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Here's the relevant code

```
int smtp_test_method(int socket)
{
    int smtp_code;

    if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "VRFY root\r\n")) == 501 ||
                                                smtp_code == 250 ||
                                                smtp_code == 252)
        return 0;
    else if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, 
                            "MAIL FROM:test@test.com\r\n")) == 250) {
        if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "RCPT TO:root\r\n")) == 250 || 
                                                          smtp_code == 550)
            return 1;
    } else 
    return smtp_code;
}
```

Where smtp_speak is a function that connects/EHLO's to a server and then sends a message, returning the response code as an int. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Not every path in this function has a return.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "control reaches end of non-void function" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a return statement after your second `if`:

```
if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "RCPT TO:root\r\n")) == 250 || smtp_code == 550)
   return 1;
**else
   return something;**
```

Comment: @user3408678 Now the question makes no sense.

Comment: I rolled it back so that the question retains its value.

Answer (score 0):

I added `{}` around each `return something;` and auto re-formatted.

The result is then clear.

1) Use auto formating.
2) Use `{}` around `if/else` blocks

```
int smtp_test_method(int socket) {
  int smtp_code;

  if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "VRFY root\r\n")) == 501
      || smtp_code == 250 || smtp_code == 252) {
    0;
  } else if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "MAIL FROM:test@test.com\r\n"))
      == 250) {
    if ((smtp_code = smtp_speak(socket, "RCPT TO:root\r\n")) == 250
        || smtp_code == 550) {
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    return smtp_code;
  }
  /* Missing return */
}
```