# Unexpected warning (-Wreturn-type) being generated

Tags: c++, string

I have to my best of knowledge written a code representing solution to this problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/make-it-anagram-mglines/problem

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int convert(char alphabet) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i<=26;i++)
    {
        if ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i-1] == alphabet)
            return i;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    string a,b;
    getline(cin, a);
    getline(cin, b);
    int l1 = a.length();
    int l2 = b.length();
    int l3 = max(l1,l2);
    int i, ans;
    ans = 0;
    int count1[26],count2[26];
    for (i=1;i<=l1;i++)
        count1[convert(a[i-1])-1]++;
    for (i=1;i<=l2;i++)
        count2[convert(b[i-1])-1]++;
    for (i=1;i<=26;i++)
        ans+= count1[i-1]+count2[i-1]-2*(min(count1[i-1],count2[i-1]));
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have not idea why I'm getting this warning while trying to run:

```
test.cpp:14:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "control reaches end of non-void function" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean)

Comment: Ask yourself, what happens if `alphabet` doesn't match?  What do you return then?

Comment: @NathanOliver, If it doesn't it doesn't. But it is given in the problem constraints that only ascii characters would be given as input.

Comment: @RameshAgarwal You might know that, but there is no way for the compiler to know that.  All it knows is that if you fail to find a match, then you don't return anything, even though you promised you would (by giving the function a non-void return type.

Comment: @RameshAgarwal You could return `-1`, if there is no match.