# Setup() runnunig more than once. Using PlatformIO in VS Code

Tags: arduino, platformio

Hey I am working on a small project and I somehow managed to cause that setup is running more than once and on top of that new code won't upload to the board. I am not entirely sure what it is I've done wrong but I can't find answer so I am asking you guys.

```
void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // I want to make some sound to tell the user to start measuring so I'll put some code below
  Serial.print("Inicialize setup");
  while (millis() < 5000)
  {
    if (millis() % 1000)
    {
      Serial.print(millis());
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
    if (AnalogValue > MaxIntensity)
    {
      MaxIntensity = AnalogValue;
    }
    if (AnalogValue < MinIntensity)
    {
      MinIntensity = AnalogValue;
    }
  }
  Serial.print("setup done");
  float MaxDist = Distance(MaxIntensity);
  float MinDist = Distance(MinIntensity);
  float delta = MaxDist - fabs(MinDist);
  Segmentlength = delta / 7;

  for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
  {
    TonesUpperValues[i] = MinDist + (Segmentlength * i);
  }
}
```

And this is the function used above

```
float Distance(int Intensity)
//function to calculate distance from intensity
{
  float d = (1 / (exp(Intensity + EOffset))) + Offset;
  d *= -1;
  return d;
}
```

In serial monitor I see the millis being printed over and over and also some text which I am guessing is `"inicialize setup"` and  `"Setup done"`
When I try to upload the code this error appears:`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM5": Access is denied.` even though : `Auto-detected: COM5`
Also previous code(the one that can't be overwritten by a new upload and is currently running had this warning in function that was not part of setup:`src\main.cpp:38:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Do you guys see any mistakes that I've made?

Comment: Try loading a simple blink program - follow the suggestions of @Arkadip below.  You can tell the Serial monitor not to scroll; try to capture the start of output. As long as you get compile errors, you aren't uploading new code. This `millis() % 1000` just gives you a number between 0 and 999 - it will be true 999/1000 times so that's why you're getting a  *LOT* of numbers printed. You could try this instead: `(millis() % 1000) == 0` but that will rarely be true - you'd likely miss 1000,2000,3000,4000 before the first `if` takes you out of the loop in `setup()`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code snippet, I am not totally sure what's happening with your code. But I found some problems, which I hope will help you.

1. For `avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM5": Access is denied.` issue,

- Arduino not always recognize the board automatically. So, make sure you have selected the correct com port using ***Tools > Port***. You must see your Arduino there
- If the board is not there, make sure you have connected the Arduino correctly i.e the LED on the Arduino is lit.
- If you have connected the board correctly, but the board is still not shown, then make sure the `Arduino USB driver` is installed properly. ReInstall the `Arduino IDE` to install the USB driver.

2. Your code snippet does not have the `void loop()`. If you are not using the `void loop()`, then leave it blank, but never miss it. It will lead to a compiler error.
3. For `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` error, Please go through this [What does "control reaches end of non-void function" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171500/what-does-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-mean)

Hope this will help you. Thanks